# Powershell to launch .exe with parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

We tried to launch an .exe file which contains text file using powershell but the .exe file is getting launched still the parameters are not getting passed

```
$gs = "E:\Main.exe"
$arguments = "Age"
Start-Process $gs $arguments -Wait
```

We tried with above cmdlet. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: How did you determine that the arguments aren't being passed?

Comment: While running this code the exe file got launched but the .exe file contains textbox which didn't get passed here and the console also able to print the passed variable if we remove -Wait from code

Comment: I think `-Wait` might modify the way PowerShell launches the process. Try with `$p = Start-Process $gs $arguments -PassThru; $p.WaitForExit()`?

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen While executing code we tried to print the argumet variable in console which got printed and the .exe file also got launched we have textbox in our .exe file we have to pass arguments there

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen Thanks you for your quick response.I tried but still the textbox in .exe file is idle

Comment: Are you sure your exe supports command line arguments? It sounds like you are launching an exe which prompts for data entry, but this is not the same as a command line argument.

Comment: Once "main.exe" has been launched, find it in Task Manager and add the "Command line" column so you can see the exact command used to launch the app. That'll tell you whether it's an issue with ```Start-Process``` launching the exe incorrectly, or an issue with the exe not parsing the parameters properly (or maybe not even supporting the parameters you expect it to).

Comment: Can you also confirm that launching "main.exe" from the command line works as expected? (e.g. ```E:\Main.exe Age```)

Comment: David and mclayton  you both are correct I could launch my .exe file from command line but not the parameters .Is there any way to do this

Comment: Try launching `E:\Main.exe /?` to see if it can handle parameters and if so in what form

Comment: @Theo its just launching the .exe file

Comment: You might need to get in touch with whoever wrote ```Main.exe``` and ask them for help working out what command line parameters you need to use (or if it even supports what you're trying to do). Once you can launch it manually on the command line with the desired behaviour you can try to automate that with PowerShell...